# Splashscreen takes too long

Tags: angular, ionic2

How can I get the splashscreentime down in my project? I tried cropping the images, but that doesn't seem too help much. It takes 11 seconds now..
I changed the standard value to 3000ms, not helping..
It's an ionic2 angular2 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config.xml add

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

Then in your app.component.ts add the following

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
     }
}
```

This way your Splashscreen only disappears when your app is ready. This should be much faster than 10 seconds